filtered port with windows firewall
Under Windows server 2022, I've blocked port 21 UDP/TCP (I do not use it anyway !!)
But:
nmap -SV <my_server> 

still continues to give me :
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp   filtered ftp

why ?
I always though that a port without any rule was, by default, closed.
Is it because of the "Stealth Mode" used by the firewall ?


I always though that a port without any rule was, by default, closed.

Those are kind of distinct things. Usually you get closed in nmap if the initial packet can get through the firewall but is explicitly refused by the OS itself, whereas firewall-blocked packets result in filtered in nmap.
But the default rule in Windows Firewall is actually to block incoming packets that don't have their own rule, so your manual block doesn't achieve much.

Is it because of the "Stealth Mode" used by the firewall ?

Yes, by default Windows Firewall enforces "stealth" behavior for all ports that aren't open in both senses of the term. That is, both "firewall blocked" and "firewall allowed but no listener" get the stealth treatment, and only "firewall allowed and listener present" is fully open.
If you disable stealth mode, then "firewall blocked" packets will still be quietly dropped but at least "firewall allowed but no listener" will correctly get a TCP RST in return.



Windows Firewall behavior
OS behavior
nmap result




quietly drop ("Block")
n/a
filtered


pass through ("Allow")
no listener – quietly drop ("stealth mode")
filtered


pass through ("Allow")
no listener – reply with TCP Reset (non-stealth-mode)
closed


pass through ("Allow")
listener present – reply with TCP Ack
open



